# How to remove the www. prefix in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-3

How do I remove the www. from incoming requests? Do I need to setup a 301 redirect or simply just rewrite the path? Either way, what's the best way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Why didn't you just add CNAME that points `www.domain.com` to `domain.com`?

Comment: *Where* do you want to remove it? Do you want to remove it *within your application*? Or do you want *your users* to never see a "www." address even if they type it?

Comment: @Mauricio what I want is even when they type in www I want it removed.

Comment: no-www.com approves this message.

Answer (score 7):

I believe it would be more appropriate to do that with IIS' URL rewriting module.

If you have access to IIS' management tool, there's a GUI to set up rewrite rules, in the "IIS" section of your site's settings.  If you choose "Add Rule(s)..." from there (in the right column menu), choose the "Canonical domain name" rule in the SEO section to almost completely automate getting the rule set up.

If not, the rewrite rule would look like this in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="CanonicalHostNameRule1">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^yourdomain\.com$" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://yourdomain.com/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I must be missing something here. If I insert that in my web.config, I get "HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid." I remove the rewrite-section, things work again. Any ideas what I am missing here?

Comment: @Kjensen: Make sure you have the URL Rewrite extension installed. You can get it here: http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the `Application.BeginRequest` event and check whether `Request.Host` starts with `www`.
If it does, call `Response.RedirectPermanent`, and pass a URL with the request's path and the naked domain.

You can construct the new URL by writing

```
"yourdomain.com" + Request.Url.PathAndQuery
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a great solution here: http://nayyeri.net/remove-quotwwwquot-from-urls-in-asp-net

```
public class RemoveWWWPrefixModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose() { }

    private static Regex regex = new Regex("(http|https)://www\\.", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
    }

    void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = sender as HttpApplication;
        Uri url = application.Context.Request.Url;
        bool hasWWW = regex.IsMatch(url.ToString());

        if (hasWWW)
        {
            String newUrl = regex.Replace(url.ToString(),
            String.Format("{0}://", url.Scheme));
            application.Context.Response.RedirectPermanent(newUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following rewrite rule in the web.config file.

This rewrite rule will remove the WWW and also keep the trailing url and the initiating protocol.

```
    <rewrite>
       <rules>
          <clear/>
             <rule name="Canonical host name" enabled="true">
                <match url="(.*)"/>
                <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="false" pattern="^www\.(.+)$"/>
                    <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(.+)://" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{C:2}://{C:1}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent"/>
             </rule>
       </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is more generic configuration as you can write it once in the URL Rewrite of the root IIS (not specific to a certain application pool) and it will automatically be applied to ALL your IIS websites without any dependency on your domain name.

[image: IIS Remove WWW]

Answer (score 0):

Much easier solution would be to create action filter and decorate your action with it.

```
public class RemovePrefix : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
                var url = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.ToString().Replace("http://www.", "http://");
                filterContext.Result = new RedirectResult(url);

    }
}
```